# APK video playback not working properly (Lenovo Tab M10 Plus)

Tags: android, flutter, video, apk, playback

Hi I have built an APK using Flutter that is used to display images and videos on a loop but the videos doesnt seem to be displaying properly.

The sequence of my display is firstly a screensaver that is constantly on loop. Upon tapping the screen it will display Video 1, Picture 1, Video 2, Picture 2, Video 3, Video 4 and once finished, it will go back to the screensaver.

Upon launching the APK app, screensaver works fine. Upon tapping on the screen, video 1, picture1, video 2, picture 2 are displaying correctly. However, video 3 and video 4 do not display and instead it goes back to the screensaver.

Then, screensaver function works as per normal and upon tapping on the screen again, it only display  picture 1, picture 2 and goes back to screensaver. All videos are not being displayed.

The APK file worked perfectly fine on other android devices e.g. Samsung Galaxy S20 but I would need it to be working on the Lenovo Tab M10 Plus (Lenovo TB128XU) which I am facing this issue.

I ran the APK on logcat via Android Studio and encounter these errors:

`[OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -12`

`signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -12)`

`Codec reported err 0xfffffff4/NO_MEMORY, actionCode 0, while in state 0/UNINITIALIZED`

`Video codec error c0.z$b: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640028, -1, null, [1080, 1920, 30.0], [-1, -1])`

`Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffff4`

`Playback error l.t: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640028, -1, null, [1080, 1920, 30.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES`

`Caused by: c0.z$b: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640028, -1, null, [1080, 1920, 30.0], [-1, -1])`

`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error l.t: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640028, -1, null, [1080, 1920, 30.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)`

Video_player widget codes:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class SlideShowApp extends StatefulWidget {
const SlideShowApp({Key? key, required this.mediaUrls, required 
this.onSlideshowEnd}) : super(key: key);

final List<String> mediaUrls;
final VoidCallback onSlideshowEnd;

@override
_SlideShowAppState createState() => _SlideShowAppState();
}

class _SlideShowAppState extends State<SlideShowApp> {
late dynamic _currentMedia;
late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
int currentIndex = 0;

Timer? _imageTimer;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_currentMedia = _initializeMedia(widget.mediaUrls[currentIndex]);
}

dynamic _initializeMedia(String url) {
String fileType = getFileTypeFromUrl(url);
print('filetype: $fileType');
if (fileType == 'video') {
  print('Video is in: $url');
  _videoPlayerController = 
VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(url))
    ..initialize().then((_) {
      _videoPlayerController.play();
      setState(() {});
    })
    ..addListener(() {
      int duration = 
_videoPlayerController.value.duration.inSeconds ~/ 4;
      print('duration: $duration');
      // Set up the timer here for videos
      _imageTimer?.cancel();
      _imageTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: duration), () {
        _showNextMedia();
      });
    });




  return AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
    child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
  );
} else if (fileType == 'image') {
  print('Image is in: $url');

  _imageTimer?.cancel();

  _imageTimer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    print('In Timer');
    _showNextMedia();
  });

  // Display image directly
  return Image.network(
    url,
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  );
} else {
  return const SizedBox.shrink(); // Unknown file type, display 
nothing
  }
}

 void _showNextMedia() {
// Dispose the current media controller
if (_currentMedia is VideoPlayerController) {
  (_currentMedia as VideoPlayerController).dispose();
}

// Move to the next media
currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;

print('currentIndex: $currentIndex');
// Check if the end of the list is reached
if (currentIndex < widget.mediaUrls.length) {
  // Cancel the image timer if it exists
  _imageTimer?.cancel();

  // Initialize and show the next media
  setState(() {
    _currentMedia = 
_initializeMedia(widget.mediaUrls[currentIndex]);
  });
} else {
  // Slideshow has reached the end, you can handle this as needed
  widget.onSlideshowEnd();
  Navigator.pop(context);
  print('Slideshow reached the end.');
  }
}

@override
void dispose() {
if (_currentMedia is VideoPlayerController) {
  (_currentMedia as VideoPlayerController).dispose();
}

_imageTimer?.cancel();
super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: _currentMedia is VideoPlayerController
      ? _initializeVideoPlayerFuture
      : Future.value(null),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      return _currentMedia;
    } else {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
       }
     },
   );
  }
}

String getFileTypeFromUrl(String url) {
String extension = url.split('.').last.toLowerCase();
if (extension == 'mp4') {
return 'video';
} else if (extension == 'jpg' || extension == 'jpeg') {
return 'image';
}
return 'unknown';
}
```

Appreciate some help here thank you

Comment: i don't know too much about this topic but i'd imagine it would be easier for people to help if you added some relevant code, perhaps add what you think is causing the problem ? just enough for others to try and recreate the problem is usually the point

Comment: i have added in the codes for the widget video player above. im honestly not sure if this could just be a device specific issue because the APK is working fine on my samsung device but just not working on my other lenovo device

Comment: i'm sure someone here will be able to answer that