# Video playback APK working on Android mobile device but not on Android tablet

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, apk

I built a 4 video loop APK using flutter and imported it into 3 devices but all 3 devices are showing different behaviour.

Emulator (Google Nexus 7 & Pixel 3) - (APK works perfectly fine)

Samsung Galaxy S20 (APK works perfectly fine)

Samsung Galaxy Tab A (4 videos play correctly but doesn't loop)

Lenovo Tab M10 Plus (Only 2 videos play and doesn't loop)

All are using Android Version 13.

Video_player_widget codes:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class SlideShowApp extends StatefulWidget {
const SlideShowApp({Key? key, required this.mediaUrls, required 
this.onSlideshowEnd}) : super(key: key);

final List<String> mediaUrls;
final VoidCallback onSlideshowEnd;

@override
_SlideShowAppState createState() => _SlideShowAppState();
}

class _SlideShowAppState extends State<SlideShowApp> {
late dynamic _currentMedia;
late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
int currentIndex = 0;

Timer? _imageTimer;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_currentMedia = _initializeMedia(widget.mediaUrls[currentIndex]);
}

dynamic _initializeMedia(String url) {
String fileType = getFileTypeFromUrl(url);
print('filetype: $fileType');
if (fileType == 'video') {
print('Video is in: $url');
_videoPlayerController = 
VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(url))
..initialize().then((_) {
  _videoPlayerController.play();
  setState(() {});
})
..addListener(() {
  int duration = 
_videoPlayerController.value.duration.inSeconds ~/ 4;
  print('duration: $duration');
  // Set up the timer here for videos
  _imageTimer?.cancel();
  _imageTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: duration), () {
    _showNextMedia();
  });
});




return AspectRatio(
aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
);
} else if (fileType == 'image') {
print('Image is in: $url');

_imageTimer?.cancel();

_imageTimer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
print('In Timer');
_showNextMedia();
});

// Display image directly
return Image.network(
url,
width: double.infinity,
height: double.infinity,
fit: BoxFit.cover,
);
} else {
return const SizedBox.shrink(); // Unknown file type, display 
nothing
  }
}

void _showNextMedia() {
// Dispose the current media controller
if (_currentMedia is VideoPlayerController) {
(_currentMedia as VideoPlayerController).dispose();
}

// Move to the next media
currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;

print('currentIndex: $currentIndex');
// Check if the end of the list is reached
if (currentIndex < widget.mediaUrls.length) {
// Cancel the image timer if it exists
_imageTimer?.cancel();

// Initialize and show the next media
setState(() {
_currentMedia = 
_initializeMedia(widget.mediaUrls[currentIndex]);
 });
} else {
// Slideshow has reached the end, you can handle this as needed
widget.onSlideshowEnd();
Navigator.pop(context);
print('Slideshow reached the end.');
  }
}

@override
void dispose() {
if (_currentMedia is VideoPlayerController) {
(_currentMedia as VideoPlayerController).dispose();
}

_imageTimer?.cancel();
super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
 future: _currentMedia is VideoPlayerController
  ? _initializeVideoPlayerFuture
  : Future.value(null),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
  return _currentMedia;
} else {
  return const Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
       }
     },
   );
  }
}

String getFileTypeFromUrl(String url) {
String extension = url.split('.').last.toLowerCase();
if (extension == 'mp4') {
return 'video';
} else if (extension == 'jpg' || extension == 'jpeg') {
return 'image';
}
return 'unknown';
}
```

Errors from logcat:

`[OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -12`

`signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -12)`

`Codec reported err 0xfffffff4/NO_MEMORY, actionCode 0, while in state 0/UNINITIALIZED`

`Video codec error c0.z$b: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640028, -1, null, [1080, 1920, 30.0], [-1, -1])`

`Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffff4`

`Playback error l.t: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640028, -1, null, [1080, 1920, 30.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES`

`Caused by: c0.z$b: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640028, -1, null, [1080, 1920, 30.0], [-1, -1])`

`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error l.t: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640028, -1, null, [1080, 1920, 30.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)`

Thank you

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of your prior question [APK video playback not working properly (Lenovo Tab M10 Plus)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77677686/295004) and the closed [APK working on Android mobile device but not on Android tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77686628/295004). Repost of questions for attention seeking will be closed as duplicates. Update your original question with details. Be aware that the hardware on Lenovo is different and you should try to experiment with lower resolution (720p) videos to see if you get a similar problem.

Comment: i have tested using different video resolution and each has different behaviour

404p - able to loop video 5 times,
540p - able to loop video 3 times,
720p - able to loop video 2 times,
1080p - not able to loop video